# How I can use array with onchange in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use `Array` for multiple data in `onchange` element but is this an accurate coding?

For example:

```
<select id="Years" onchange="showContent('Years', array('rightPanelTxt', 'hrefDataAttr'))">
```

Javascript:

```
function showContent($kaynak, $gosterilecekKonum) {

    var $gosterilecekKonum = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $gosterilecekKonum.length; i++) {

        var selected_secenek = document.getElementById($kaynak).value;
        document.getElementById($gosterilecekKonum[i]).innerText = selected_secenek;
        $($gosterilecekKonum[i]).attr('data-bid', selected_secenek);
    };

}
```

Console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined

`gosterilecekKonum` This is array
Thank you

Comment: No, you cannot create an array like that in an HTML tag. You should investigate setting your array in code and the use `.addEventListener()` to use that array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following part

```
onchange="showContent('Years', array('rightPanelTxt', 'hrefDataAttr'))"
```

Here you trying to call a function named `array` with parameters `'rightPanelTxt', 'hrefDataAttr'`. The function `array` is not defined. You should pass the the array containing the values. Like below

```
onchange="showContent('Years', ['rightPanelTxt', 'hrefDataAttr'])"
```

Comment: This is all code. I removed this element `array` from HTML and only worked for this element => `rightPanelTxt` - I think this part is not working `$($gosterilecekKonum[i]).attr('data-bid', selected_secenek);`

Comment: @J. Doe Your `html` is incomplete I guess.